# Timer.Elapsed fire event only once,I want it every Second

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

Timers.Timer to create StopWatch. I use Timer.Elapsed to handle event that display time after perticular time. I give timer interval of 1 and enabled to true. I also make AutoReset to true. But the problem is event is firing only once.and  I get time in Textbox only once.How can I change Time in TextBox Every Second.I try all alternatives but not get success...Thank You

```
    System.Timers.Timer StopWatchTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
     public void StopwatchStartBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        StopWatchTimer.Start();
        StopWatchTimer.Interval = 1;
        StopWatchTimer.Enabled = true;
        StopWatchTimer.AutoReset =true; 
        sw.Start();
        StopWatchTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(StopWatchTimer_Tick);
    }

    protected void StopWatchStopBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBoxStopWatch.Text = "00:00:000";
        StopWatchTimer.Stop();
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Stop(); 

    }

    public void StopWatchTimer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {           
   TextBoxStopWatch.Text=   Convert.ToString(sw.Elapsed);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
 I try it by creating new website in Visual Studio.But still don't get success.same problem . Now update is when I set Break Point in Line

```
     TextBoxStopWatch.Text=   Convert.ToString(sw.Elapsed);
```

Text is Continuously changing there but not displaying in TextBox. Hope You can Understand this.

Comment: When I run your code I get an InvalidOperationException.  The reason is that the StopWatchTimer_Tick method is attempting to access a control in a different thread.  What's the rest of your code?

Comment: Interestingly, if I compile and run it directly (outside of VS) it works as expected.  What version of C# are you using?

Comment: @Chris Lively .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: I noticed you mentioned that this was happening in a web app.  No wonder you didn't get the error during runtime that I did.  See my answer below.  You can't do this in a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it this way in a web page.

By the time the page is rendered, the server is done and the client has disconnected.  It's not going to get any more updates from your timer.

If you need to have a timer on the page itself showing some changing numbers then you will have to do this via javascript.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `Start()` before you even set the parameters.  Try this:

```
StopWatchTimer.Interval = 1000; 
StopWatchTimer.AutoReset = true; 
StopWatchTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(StopWatchTimer_Tick); 
StopWatchTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Set the `Enabled` property to `true` after all of your properties are set.  (calling the `Start()` method is equivalent to setting `Enabled = true`)

Also, not sure if you're aware of this, but the `Timer.Interval` property is in milliseconds.  So you are firing the `Timer.Elapsed` event every millisecond.  Just an FYI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I should sset properties before make it start.I do it but still I get value in textbox only once than it is not going to  fire event

Comment: Try setting your interval to 1000.  And how do you know the Timer.Elapsed event is only firing once??

Comment: Actually I set BreakPoint there..After Setting it to 1000 I even don't get it once

Comment: @Hiren that may be throwing it off.  I can't say for sure.  Take the breakpoint out and try it.

Comment: Setting StopWatchTimer.Enabled = true is the same as calling the Start function. Per MSDN: "Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start, while setting Enabled to false is the same as calling Stop."

Comment: @Hiren see my edit.  Setting `Enabled = true` is actually causing your events to start.  See the code in my post and try that out.  You don't need to call `Start()` *and* set `Enabled = true`.  Just set `Enabled = true` after your set your properties and event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to take into account that the text box's content should only be altered by the UI thread and not the callback context. Are you taking an exception on the callback? 
Look at using the dispatcher to invoke the UI update on the main UI thread instead of the timer thread.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I rearranged things so the settings for the timer/stopwatch are only set once to avoid confusion and also dealt with the UI thread invoke.

```
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    Stopwatch stopwatch;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);

        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    public void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxStopWatch.Text = Convert.ToString(stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxStopWatch.Text = "00:00:000";
        timer.Stop();
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply I am working with Web Application not Windows application so I dont have Invoke or InvokeRequired.